# How do I expand this summation?

Tags: calculus, summation

So I just started doing these today and this has me stuck (It's a beginner question and i'm upset I'm stumped). So I have  $\sum_{k=1}^{4}9k\sin(\frac{k\pi}{2})$ which I turn into $9\sum_{k=1}^{4}k\sin(\frac{k\pi}{2})$ annnnnnd that is as far as I got. How do I go about expanding this summation, thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the expression $\sin x = {1 \over 2i} (e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$?

Comment: No, never seen it.

Comment: Sorry, I though the summation was infinite. In fact, I wasn't paying attention...

Comment: It's all good, no worries.

Comment: $\sin {k \pi \over 2} = { i^k-(-i)^k \over 2 i}$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\sin\frac\pi2=1,\sin n\pi=0,\sin\left(\pi+\frac\pi2\right)=-\sin\frac\pi2$$

Answer (score 2):

The sequence given by
$$a_k = \sin\frac{\pi k}{2}$$
is periodic and fairly simple, you have 
$$ a_0=0,\quad a_1=1,\quad a_2=0, \quad a_3=-1,\quad a_4=0,\quad a_5=1,\quad\ldots$$
hence your sum just equals $9\cdot 1-9\cdot 3 = -18.$